# clion github error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, github, clion

When I try to share a new project on github via VSS--Import into Version Control--Share project on GitHub, I get the following error:

Can't finish GitHub sharing process
                Successfully created project xyz on GitHub, but initial push failed:
                unable to access 'https://github.com/username/xyz.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:

In settings--Version Control--GitHub my github account is working in the settings when I press test button with password authentication. Furthermore as the error states the project is created on github but no files are committed.

In Settings-Version Control--Git i have pointed to my git\bin\git.exe and the test  is successful. Switching SSH executable from built-in doesn't make any different. On subsequent push i get same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificates? Use (with care) the -c sslVerify option for git:

`git -c sslVerify=false clone blahblah`

That should work. I don't set it on config globally or on repos because I think it's "risky" so I rather use it on the git calls I need.